# React app not rendering inside react-native-webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am planning to show my react app inside react-native-webview. I implement the code for WebView. When I put URL https://www.w3schools.com , It works perfectly. But when I used my react app URL https://jshossen.com/ it not rendering anything. It only shows a white screen. Anyone help me with whats I have to do to run React App inside WebView?

[image]

[image]

This is my code sample:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, Platform, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.topContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          // source={{ uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/' }}
          source={{ uri: 'https://jshossen.com' }}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: '100%', 
    width: '100%',
  },
  topContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  }
});


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<WebView source={{ uri: url }} 
          style={{ resizeMode: 'cover', flex: 1 }}
          injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=2.0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
          scalesPageToFit={false}
        />

This should work, please have a test
```

Comment: I tried. Same issue w3school works. But not my react app :( .